# MongoDB/Mongoose - "unset" when empty or false-y

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Does anyone know of a good way (either natively in MongoDB or through Mongoose) to "unset" a document property when it's empty?

Use case: I have an optional secondary email address field. It's not a required field and it defaults to undefined. But once it's populated, I'm finding it difficult to clear the value again.

I'd normally use a pre-save middleware, but when using transactions, those don't seem to fire.

The behavior I'd like is that whenever the value is false-y (empty string, null, etc.) it should be unset from the document.

I've thought of writing static methods into my various schema to purge some of these fields, but that seems heavy-handed

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is the thing that you looking for

```
let filters = [ null,false, "undefined",""];

db.collectionName.updateOne({
  optionalEmail: {
    "$in":filters
  }
}, {
  "$unset": {
    optioanlEmail: ""
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I'm sorry for my delayed reply. In the end, I chose to write an "object packing" utility that will delete "false-y" or replace them with "default" value from a skeleton object. I think that worked best for me.

I did feel like I was reinventing the wheel, but I also found it helpful for my case to know the context of the model and whether it was "okay" for a given model to store nulls, empty strings, and boolean false values. 

So for my case, there was too much context sensitivity for me to rely on a one-size-fits-all approach.